# swift check if device token has changed

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

my swift 2 app works with push notifications.
i save the deviceToken into a NSUserDefaults.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
            var deviceTokenString = String(deviceToken)
            deviceTokenString = String(deviceTokenString.characters.dropLast())
            deviceTokenString = String(deviceTokenString.characters.dropFirst())
            deviceTokenString = deviceTokenString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
            defaults.setObject("\(deviceTokenString)", forKey: "DeviceToken")
    }
```

i would like to check (for example on each app start) if the device token has changed.

where and how i can check this?
should I register the device every time again to check, which token i receive and compare this with the token in the NSUserDefaults?

or is there an better way?

Comment: Usually you do that on server side where the notifications are sent. What can you do with the token on client side?

Comment: Just one question- Do you have two applications with the same login and you have to use push notification for both the app?

Comment: i only have one app with a login. i save the device token in my mysql database, too. but when is the best time, to check if the device token has change?

Comment: I know i am too late to answer this. But for other users this may be useful.

Apple states:

 "The device token is your key to sending push notifications to your app on a specific device. Device tokens can change, so your app needs to reregister every time it is launched and pass the received token back to your server." 

So we should register for token every time. We can have local check for comparing old token & revived token. If it is different , update it to your server.